# Custom .net azure-data factory activity

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm getting this error when I try to implement `HttpDataDownloaderSample` using `CustomDotNetActivity` in `Azure-DataFactory`:

```
Unknown error in module:
System.InvalidOperationException: The type
DataDownloaderActivityNS.DataDownloaderActivity in the
DataDownloaderActivity assembly does not exist or doesn't implement the
type Microsoft.DataFactories.Runtime.IDotNetActivity properly. Please
check your configuration. Names are case sensitive on each single
character.
at
Microsoft.DataPipeline.Compute.HDInsightJobExecution.JobWrapper.LoadToAppDomain(AssemblyName
assemblyFullName, String typeName) in
f:\_Bld\12751\6742\Sources\Product\Common\Compute\src\HDIComputeDelegatorJob\JobWrapper.cs:line
130 at Microsoft.DataPipeline.Compute.HDInsightJobExecution.JobWrapper.RunJob()
in
f:\_Bld\12751\6742\Sources\Product\Common\Compute\src\HDIComputeDelegatorJob\JobWrapper.cs:line
83
at
Microsoft.DataPipeline.Compute.HDInsightJobExecution.Launcher.Main(String[]
args) in
f:\_Bld\12751\6742\Sources\Product\Common\Compute\src\HDIComputeDelegatorJob\Launcher.cs:line
78.
```

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: What does the method signature of the "Execute" method look like that you are trying to run?

Comment: It looks like this "Execute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)"

Comment: Just to verify you have taken the zipped source code and uploaded it to azure blob storage and linked it in the activity json definition?

Comment: I did everything in the sample. I put all the dll files in the root folder, zipped it and uploaded it in the azure blob storage and linked it in the activity pipeline definition. I've exhausted all the resources online and also tried to recreate the whole process a couple of times but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the sample you are using but I have had this exact error with a Custom Activity. After chasing the 'doesn't implement the type' error fruitlessly, it turned out to be due to the Input and Outputs on my pipeline being set to the same Dataset. This produces a recursive Dataset error. However, you won't see this error in the above trace.

I eventually found the recrusive error was when resetting the slice in Powershell to re-run it. This gave a much more meaningful error. To do this, open Powershell and Log in with `Login-AzureRmAccount` and then issue a `Set-AzureRmDataFactorySliceStatus` for each Dataset linked to your pipeline.

This may help diagnose it. The IDotNetActivity error was a complete red herring for me. Fixing the datasets solved the problem.

Documentation for resetting slices with Powershell : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/set-azurermdatafactoryslicestatus?view=azurermps-6.13.0